# can we post pics on our ig (private account) having all female frndz?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, authenticity

I have my private account on instagram.I used to post my pictures and all my male and female cousins and friends used to watch them. pics are not inappropriate just those random clicks. Recently i removed all my male cousins as non-mehram should not watch your pics but did not remove my female frnds so just wanted to make sure that is it okay that my female frndz watch my pics.

Comment: If those female friends are righteous Muslimahs, so that you can trust that they will not further share or show those pics to male non-mahrams. And if you can have reasonable trust on Instagram itself against privacy breaches or data leaks. The safest approach is to not do it, to avoid showing yourself in the pictures, or to edit yourself out, or to make sure that proper hijab is observed etc.